# need help to copy only numbers from webpage Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, numbers, copy

[Elements in webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQDzl.png)

```
<td style="font-size:20px;font-family:LucidaGrande,tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;padding:10px;background-color:#f2f2f2;border-left:1px solid #ccc;border-right:1px solid #ccc;border-top:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">FB-91927</td>
```

not find class or id or name to select

and i need copy only numbers not all text

```
<li class="title">FB-91927 is your Facebook confirmation code</li>
```

I tried to copy it from the title

```
driver.find_elements_by_class("title")
```

But I don't know how to identify numbers only from text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G81sP.png)

Answer (score 1):

To identify numbers from text, you can use regex (regular expressions)

```
import re


text = "FB-19876 is your code"
code = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
print(code)
```

The output for above example will be `['19876']`, which you can then extract using list operations. You can modify the regex based on the requirements.

Comment: But the number is always variable, not a fixed number

Comment: Yes, + in regex can match 1 or more digits in a string, so even if the number changes or has different number of digits, it should work. Can you give an example string where this code will not work?